# ! Font \csname\endcsname=rsfs10 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, errors

I'm a Latex beginner and am using Latex to do a project. Everything was fine before this problem. I had no idea how to figure this out. I'm currently using texmaker on my Macbook to edit my Latex file. Below are my original settings for the file:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float} 



\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumerate}

% Times new roman font
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
% Preserve mathcal
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{observation}{Observation}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem*{comments}{Note}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}

\let\oldproof\proof
\renewcommand{\proof}{\color{black}\oldproof}
\let\oldsol\solution
\renewcommand{\solution}{\color{blue}\oldsol}
\date{}
```

The problem arises when I typed the following code, which seems normal:

```
$\frac{dS}{dt} = -rSI - \lambda $
```

I don't know what happened

Comment: make a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue. And say also which texsystem (miktex, texlive?) you are using.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your comments. I'm currently using Texmaker. I doubt that I didn't include some files when I was installing Latex...

Comment: texmaker is only an editor, not a tex system. Check your log-file, it should tell you what you use.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The log reports me: ! Font \csname\endcsname=rsfs10 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found, which is the title of my question...

Comment: that is not the only thing the log contains. It also should show your texsytem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's weird that I put exactly the same code into overleaf just now, and it returned no error and the file was compiled just fine. I'm also confused about this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, before that line in the log, there's probably another error: "Font Info: Font shape 'OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available"

Comment: look if you want help you should provide information. I asked you know already the third time what you are using for a texsystem and if you don't start to answer I will let you alone.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm sorry, it's texlive.

Comment: and which version? Did you install a full texlive?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It shows my texlive is "2021 basic"

Comment: version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021)

Comment: well then you are probably missing the font package. Install rsfs with the texlive manager (or whatever you have to do to install packages).